# How do I make MINGW not wait for Sublime Text to close before accepting more commands?

Tags: powershell, command, mingw, sublimetext

On my Windows, I managed to get sublime text become a command on my MINGW terminal. I'm able to open sublime text itself or open sublime text with a text file. However, the terminal won't accept more commands until I close the terminal. It's similar to calling vim, where vim needs to exit before it accepts more commands. But sublime is its own window, so there's no reason for a terminal to wait. What is the way to configure a command in such a way that we don't wait for it to terminate before the terminal accept more commands?

Answer (score 2):

Is it a bash compatible shell?

> The most obvious way of doing might be to append an `&` to the end of
>   the command. This detaches the command from `stdin` which means the
>   shell isn’t tied up by the command and you can execute other commands.
>   However, the command's process is still managed by the shell and
>   stdout and stderr are still attached to the shell session. This means
>   that when the shell session ends (you close your terminal window, exit
>   ssh, etc) the command’s process is sent a `HUP` signal, which usually
>   terminates the command.

Refrence:

- [Running bash commands in the background properly](https://felixmilea.com/2014/12/running-bash-commands-background-properly)